# Building Applescript ObjectSpecifier With Name in Javascript

Tags: javascript, applescript, javascript-automation

Is there a way to build an ObjectSpecifier using name instead of array number in Javascript Applescript?

```
search = ObjectSpecifier().buttons["Add"].value
items = items.groups.whose({_match:[search,"Selected"]})
```

The index  for "add button" is different in each item, so if I build the ObjectSpecifier with buttons[3] Instead of buttons["Add"], it only returns the items that have add button at the index 3. I also tried "ObjectSpecifier().buttons.byName("Add").value", but it doesn't work.
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

buttons["Add"].value should work. Make sure all the items in the arrays you're filtering have buttons["Add"] in them. If not, filter out the ones who don't have buttons["Add"] first, and then filter again with buttons["Add"].value.